# Pytorch object detection model optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, pytorch, faster-rcnn

I want to reduce the object detection model size. For the same, I tried optimising *Faster R-CNN* model for object detection using pytorch-mobile optimiser, but the `.pt` `zip` file generated is of the same size as that of the original model size.

I used the code mention below

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils.mobile_optimizer import optimize_for_mobile

model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

model.eval()
script_model = torch.jit.script(model)
from torch.utils.mobile_optimizer import optimize_for_mobile
script_model_vulkan = optimize_for_mobile(script_model, backend='Vulkan')
torch.jit.save(script_model_vulkan, "frcnn.pth")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to quantize your model first
follow these steps [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/quantization.html)
& then use these methods

```
from torch.utils.mobile_optimizer import optimize_for_mobile
script_model_vulkan = optimize_for_mobile(script_model, backend='Vulkan')
torch.jit.save(script_model_vulkan, "frcnn.pth")
```

EDIT:

Quantization process for resnet50 model

```
import torchvision
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
import os
import torch

def print_model_size(mdl):
    torch.save(mdl.state_dict(), "tmp.pt")
    print("%.2f MB" %(os.path.getsize("tmp.pt")/1e6))
    os.remove('tmp.pt')
print_model_size(model) # will print original model size
backend = "qnnpack"
model.qconfig = torch.quantization.get_default_qconfig(backend)
torch.backends.quantized.engine = backend
model_static_quantized = torch.quantization.prepare(model, inplace=False)
model_static_quantized = torch.quantization.convert(model_static_quantized, inplace=False)



print_model_size(model_static_quantized) ## will print quantized model size
```

Comment: I tried the quantization followed by torch scripting, it worked. Thank you. But when i tried to quantize frcnn model, got the following error, "RuntimeError: Quantized backend not supported"  `model_quantized= torchvision.models.quantization.resnet50(pretrained=True, quantize=True)`, let me know what changes needs to be done here..

Comment: can you check what this returns `torch.backends.quantized.supported_engines`. And which os are you using?

Comment: I tried `torch.backends.quantized.supported_engines`, i got ['qnnpack' , 'none']. OS is ubuntu.

Comment: 'qnnpack' ,   should be OK....need to look @ ur code once....if its private try to debug on ur own....

Comment: `import torchvision`
`model_quantized=torchvision.models.quantization.resnet18(pretrained=True`,`quantize=True)`
`model = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)'
`import os`
`import torch`

`def print_model_size(mdl):`
    `torch.save(mdl.state_dict(), "tmp1.pt")`
    `print("%.2f MB" %(os.path.getsize("tmp1.pt")/1e6))`
    `os.remove('tmp.pt')`

`print_model_size(model)`
`print_model_size(model_quantized)`    I'm trying to quantize resnet and frcnn model

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the resnet and frcnn model size and use them for object detection on edge device. Im using the same quantization method you mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: so it worked for frcnn & not resnet50..? is my understanding correct?

Comment: It only worked for mobilenetV2. I'm getting runtime error for both frcnn and resnet while quantizing it.

Comment: hi i guess u have taken quantized model which are alraedy available in torchvision module and tested its file size.(which ll always execute. i ll update my answer for resnet50.plz check it.

Comment: It worked, even tried for frcnn. Thank you.

Comment: can u plz mark it as correct answer and vote it ;-)

Comment: and also the vote(this answer is useful)?